# Removing border from Flowdecision icon in workflow foundation

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Is any way to remove border from FlowDecision icon in Workflow Foundation?

Currently I have something like that:
[FlowDecision with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8eSH.png)

and I would like to make it easier like that: [FlowDecision without border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTsWB.png)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no function to disable the borders of a FlowDecision. 
If you want a custom look you can create a custom activity with an [Activity Designer](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/963/workflow-foundation-40-activity-designer) and a CodeActivity. But it will have rectangular borders. Also you have to implement the condition part...So if the functionality of the actual FlowDecision fits your needs it's may the best way to stay with the defult look of the FlowDecision.